# Leaving raw chicken uncovered for a day

Tags: food-safety, chicken, storage, raw

I sometimes leave some chicken unwrapped in the fridge inside the container, if I buy a two piece, and only want one. A girl who lives at my dorm told me it was a life threatening harm, to everybody’s food inside the fridge, since deadly bacteria’s spread,  to all the food. I read a similar post, where there was split descisions. Is there any danger to it, and if yes, how dangerous?

Comment: Elcome to [cooking.se]!  **:-)** What do you mean by "inside the container"?  In the vegetable compartment? In a sealed-off Tupperware?  Please leave a note @Fabby after you've [edit]ed your question so that it becomes clearer.  **;-)**

Comment: If not for food safety reasons, why not wrap it up to keep it from drying out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Food kept at refrigeration temperatures is relatively safe.  Any potential pathogens can not jump or fly about without something to propel them. Dripping can potentially contaminate. Cooking can render many things safe (if initially stored properly).  Keeping meats in closed containers is more sanitary (and respectful of others). However, to suggest that refrigerated unwrapped chicken, in a container, is "life threatening" sounds a bit extreme to me.

Answer (score 4):

Food safety guidelines suggest that raw meats are not kept above other foods. The theory is that if the raw veggies are on top, the "juice" from raw chicken will not spill into the veggies and contaminate them. While I have never heard of airborne issues, if you are sharing a refrigeration unit with others, then you should properly seal and store raw chicken out of respect for their concerns. 
[5 Simple Habits for Raw Chicken Safety](https://www.thespruceeats.com/chicken-and-poultry-safety-tips-995347)
[USDA Refrigeration and Food Safety](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/refrigeration-and-food-safety/ct_index)